# Combine two different PHP functions with the same subset of variables?

Tags: php, function

Here are two example PHP functions:

```
function myimage1() {
global $post;
    $attachment_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'f1image', $single = true);
    $myimage1 = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, thumbnail );
return $myimage1;
}
```

(I call this one like this: `<?php echo myimage1(); ?>` )

and

```
function myimage2() {
global $post;
    $attachment_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'f1image', $single = true);
    $myimage2 = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, medium );
return $myimage2;
}
```

(I call this one like this: `<?php echo myimage2(); ?>` )

As you can see, both have one common variable `$attachment_id`. And both functions are very much related, and it's just that I don't know how to combine them both, or how to call them from the combined function.

**PS:** I don't know PHP, my terminology could be a bit vague. In that case, please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myimage($level) {
    global $post;
    $attachment_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'f1image', true);
    $myimage = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $level );
    return $myimage;
}

myimage("medium");
myimage("thumbnail");
```

Answer (score 0):

OOP is exactly for this needs. Two functions (methods) uses the same class variable.

```
<?php

class A {

    public $attachment_id;

    private function wp_get_attachment_image() {

        // place your wp_get_attachment_image() function content here

    }

    public function myimage1() {

        $myimage1 = $this->wp_get_attachment_image($this->attachment_id, medium);
        return $myimage1;

    }

    public function myimage2() {

        $myimage2 = $this->wp_get_attachment_image($this->attachment_id, medium);
        return $myimage2;

    }

}

$a = new A;
$a->attachment_id = $a->get_post_meta($post->ID, 'f1image', $single = true);
$a->myimage1();
$a->myimage2();

?>
```

Comment: This is really confusing to me. Could you please modify your example with the code in my question? Also, please provide the PHP code to call each PHP function.